# When I scroll the ListView, the background image is not displayed. Why?

Tags: android

I have one custom ListView which contains one ImageView and one TextView, and I set a background. But while I am scrolling the ListView, the background image is not displayed. How can I fix this?

Black color is display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: listview.setCacheColorHint(0);

Answer (score 4):

Set the following property in your ListView in the layout file.

```
  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

That will make it so that when you scroll the background image shows up correctly.

Comment: Your welcomed; my solution works via xml; Farhan's does the same thing in code.